# Comparar data de nascimento registrada no banco com uma data personalizada - mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Boa tarde, estou exibindo um relatório, aonde é para mostrar os clientes que possuem + 60 anos.
Como eu **não** possuo um campo `idade` no bd, eu tive que "descobri-la" pela data de nascimento e fiz dessa forma:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_de_nascimento, CURDATE()) as idade FROM clientes
```

**Agora preciso especificar no `select`, que só quero que exiba quem a idade for maior que 60.**

> Eu tentei colocar **`WHERE idade >= 60`** porém, não deu certo.

Eu estou tentando comparar a **data de nascimento** com o ano de **1960** (2020 - 1960 = **60**), porém quero pegar o **dia**  e o **mês atual**, para não ter que ficar trocando sempre e ter uma busca "sem falhas", mas não estou conseguindo...
Estou tentando dessa forma:

```
WHERE data_de_nascimento <= '1960-Month(data)-Day(now))'
```

**Alguém consegue me ajudar?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Verifique se é isto o que deseja:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE data_de_nascimento <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Direto ao ponto, a forma correta de consultar é repetir a mesmo formula que usou para a coluna idade, ficando assim:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_de_nascimento, CURDATE()) as idade 
FROM clientes
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_de_nascimento, CURDATE()) >= 60
```

Um exemplo Online [Consulta Maiores de 60](https://paiza.io/projects/7Z03u_tk6Uszz2wA5GqfvA?language=mysql)

Código do Exemplo: (caso não carregue)

```
create table Test(id integer, nome varchar(100), nascimento datetime);
insert into Test(id, nome, nascimento) values(1, "Joaquim", '1960-02-15'); -- 60 anos de idade
insert into Test(id, nome, nascimento) values(1, "Manel", '1960-04-05');   -- 59 anos de idade
insert into Test(id, nome, nascimento) values(1, "Joana", '1957-08-25');   -- 62 anos de idade
insert into Test(id, nome, nascimento) values(1, "Maria", '1961-11-07');   -- 58 anos de idade
select id, nome, nascimento, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, nascimento, CURDATE()) as idade from Test
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, nascimento, CURDATE()) >= 60;
```

O MySQL trabalha com Alias para os campos, mas no momento em que vai validar a clausula Where, o campo pode estar sem valor determinado. Por este motivo existe esta restrição sobre uso de Alias no Where.

Fonte: [Manual de Referência do MySQL 8.0: Problemas com Alias dos Campos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Answer (score 1):

Como foi comentado em outra resposta o MySQL usa alias para os campos mas não permite referências para estes no WHERE.
Contudo, você pode utilizar uma clausula HAVING. O HAVING só vai ser avaliado após o cálculo já ter sido realizado e a informação de `idade` já estará disponível.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_de_nascimento, CURDATE()) as idade FROM clientes HAVING idade >= 60;
```